# how to add reference telerik.radwizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I want to use a `telerik.wizard` and I've to add reference in .aspx like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Windows.Controls" Assembly="Telerik.Windows.Controls" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik"  Namespace="Telerik.Windows.Controls" Assembly="telerik.windows.controls.navigation" %>
```

I get the error

```
The type or namespace name 'Wizard' does not exist in the namespace 'Telerik.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ASP.NET WebForms controls, reference those only, i.e., remove the two latter Register directives. Here is what you need:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

You can even add it in the web.config instead of adding it on every page, master page or user control:

```
<pages>
 <controls>
   <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
 </controls>
</pages>
```

You can read more on the basics of how to add the Telerik AJAX controls to your app here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/adding-the-telerik-controls-to-your-project